# Uploading image is not working on server

Tags: c#, asp.net

While uploading the file from local machine on to the server, it is showing me the

```
"Server Error in '/' Application.
Access to the path 'G://images\blog-image2.jpg' is denied."
```

Can someone help me out in this....Please. my c# code is this:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get Filename from fileupload control
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages.PostedFile.FileName);
    //Save images into Images folder
    fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + filename));

    //Getting dbconnection from web.config connectionstring
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
    //Open the database connection
    con.Open();
    //Query to insert images path and name into database
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tblimgs(ImageName,ImagePath) values(@ImageName,@ImagePath)", con);
    //Passing parameters to query
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", filename);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePath", "~/images/" + filename);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Close dbconnection
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
}
```

what is wrong in this?

Comment: I think you must allow writing permissions on server into this directory: G:\images\ by the user IUSER or something like that.

Comment: Try this `Server.MapPath("~\\images\\" + filename)`

Comment: I tried this also, but nothing is change....

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to make sure the account you're using has access to that file path.

Also it would probably help to give access to that folder for the IIS user account (IUSR I believe).

Comment: how can I give the access to that path?

Comment: Go to G:\images in windows explorer and right click the folder and go to Properties -> go to Security Tab -> Click Edit -> Click Add -> Type IUSR in the names box -> click check names -> select the first one if you get a popup past that. -> Click ok -> Click on the IUSR item in the list box -> select Full Control where it says Permissions for IUSR -> Click Apply -> Click Ok.  After that the IIS  user should have access to the directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check which user your application runs under, it may be that the user account will not have permissions to write to any sub-folders for security reasons. Give that user write permissions to the images folder and make sure that is the only folder that you do give it write permissions to so that the security risk is minimised.

You could also refactor you code to:

```
fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images"),filename)));
```

since `MapPath()` doesn't append a trailing backslash to the mapped path because it has no way of knowing if the path is a directory or a file (it doesn't check if the given path actually exists).

**EDIT:**
To grant the correct permissions to that folder, first you need to find out from the application pool for the website what is the identity it is running under (by default this is Application Pool Identity). Look for the IIS `APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` user. See this [article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities) on the official IIS site for more details.

If that won't work for you then check to see if your asp.net account `{MACHINE}\ASPNET` has write access to that images location. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. To do this, right click on downloading folder `Properties > Security Tab > Edit > Add > locations > choose your local machine > click OK >` Type `ASPNET` below `"Enter the object name to select" >` Click `Check Names` Check the boxes for the desired access (Full Control). If that does not work for you then consider doing the same with `Network Service`.

Now this should show your local `{MACHINENAME}\ASPNET` account, then you set the write permission to this account.

Otherwise if the application is impersonating via `<identity impersonate="true"/>`, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically `IUSR_MACHINENAME`) or the authenticated request user.

Comment: It is still showing me the same error...how can I give the permissions to the folder? i was trying from ftp..is it right? it is perfectly work when I'm running it from my local machine. it upload all the images into images folder on same server....why it is not working when I'm uploading it on to server..?